# Bundle JS and CSS for a PHP Web application?

Tags: php, webpack, requirejs, slim, slim-3

I am building a website using PHP and Slim framework. I have about 12 Javascript files and 8 CSS files and am looking to bundle them in order to decrease the number of HTTP requests. I have come across webpack and require js that might help with this problem but I don't know if those are the right options and also how to het started with it ?

Comment: you can just stick all the css in one file - copy paste, and probably the js depending on how it's written. but the number of http requests really does not matter, most modern istes make quite a few. 20 requests for this page for instance

Comment: This question is off-topic for two reasons; 1. Asking us to recommend/suggest ott-site resources, such as libraries etc, are off-topic here. 2. Questions like this will only give you opinionated answers since there are many ways you can solve your issue. Different devs have different preferences. If you found something that solves your problem, go for it.

Comment: @tim - _"but the number of http requests really does not matter"_ - Yes it does. You should always strive to make as few requests as possible. Remember that making the connection to a URL (handshakes etc) are costly so downloading all js in one request will be faster than downloading the same js spread out in 10 files.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to bundle assets. For example [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or something more specific for PHP and Slim [twig-assets](https://github.com/odan/twig-assets).